# SQL Server XML Querying

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to use a variable in place of and XML String when I query the XML field in my table.

```
CASE 
WHEN t.value('(./meta/node()[2]/value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = '101' THEN 'ABC'
WHEN t.value('(./meta/node()[2]/value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = '201' THEN 'SLM'
WHEN t.value('(./meta/node()[2]/value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = '251' THEN 'SPR'
WHEN t.value('(./meta/node()[2]/value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = '301' THEN 'FYT'
WHEN t.value('(./meta/node()[2]/value)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') = '350' THEN 'PRR'
...
```

This CASE statement have about 20 elements to it and I am trying to do something like

```
DECLARE @XMLString AS XML
SET @XMLString = './meta/node()[2]/value)[1]'
```

And then use the variable instead of writing the string each time and to make my code more dynamic. It works now but I am positive there are ways to make it more dynamic and faster than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want. If you want more details you must provide the structure of your XML and what exactly you want to achieve.

You will have to learn about `CTE`, `CROSS APPLY` and `nodes()`. Your `XPath`-expression is very likely much to complicated.

Just an example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<root>
    <meta>
        <value>Value1.1</value>
        <value>Value1.2</value>
        <value>Value1.3</value>
        <value>Value1.4</value>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <value>Value2.1</value>
        <value>Value2.2</value>
        <value>Value2.3</value>
    </meta>
    <meta>
        <value>Value3.1</value>
        <value>Value3.2</value>
    </meta>
</root>';

SELECT value.onevalue.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/meta/value') AS value(onevalue);

--You can use this directly in a case (lot of typing)
--or you could select the needed value directly to use it with less typing

SELECT MyApply.myValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/meta/value') AS value(onevalue)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT value.onevalue.value('.','varchar(max)') AS myValue) AS MyApply;
```

Comment: @WesPalmer, if this answer helped you, it would be kind of you to mark it as accepted and/or click to upvote.Thx!